# How do I drop the home phone number if it is the same as the cell phone number in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have a list of people who may have a cellphone number, a home phone number, or both. The dataset often has the same number listed for both the cellphone number and the home phone number. This is what I am trying to do for each record:

```
if cellphonenumber = (homephonenumber) then keep (cellphonenumber) and drop (homephonenumber)
```

I've tried different combinations and cannot get it to work. I am competent in writing SQL and VBA for Access and have branched into SAS. I know the syntax is different and that Access does not have the full library (i.e. does not recognize "distinct").

Comment: You cannot conditionally drop a column for a single record. Is your data in rows, ie one row is a cell phone and one is a home phone or do you have both in the same line.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways. SQL is supported in SAS, but you should familiarize yourself with the data step since it's one of SAS's most powerful tools.

**Data Step**

Let's assume your data looks like this:

```
id       home           cell
1                       111-111-0123
2        222-222-0123   222-222-0123
3        333-333-0123   444-444-0123
```

If you want to remove the home phone number, then simple `if-then` logic will work fine. In SAS, `' '` is missing for character columns, and `.` for numeric. You can optionally use the `call missing()` subroutine to automatically set it for you.

```
data want;
    set have;
    if(home = cell) then home = ' ';
run;
```

**SQL**

You can also do this in SQL:

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select id
             , CASE
                   when(home = cell) then home = ' '
                   else home
               END as home
            , cell
        from have
    ;
quit;
```

**Other info**

If your data is not clean and has leading or trailing blanks, you can loop through all of your character columns to ensure that all leading/trailing blanks are removed. If you need to standardize your home/cell numbers, you'll need to do some additional standardization logic (note that if you have access to SAS Data Quality Server, all of that can be done for you automatically).

The below will loop through every character variable and run the `strip()` function to remove leading and trailing blanks for every row.

```
data want;
    set have;
    array charvars[*] _CHARACTER_;
    
    do i = 1 to dim(charvars);
        charvars[i] = strip(charvars[i]);
    end;

    if(home = cell) then home = ' ';

    drop i;
run;
```

Take a look at [SAS's free e-learning](https://support.sas.com/edu/schedules.html?crs=PROG1&ctry=US) for training on SAS programming concepts.

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up using the first code with (home = cell) and it worked perfectly! The entire code is pretty robust, so I was able to fit the new lines perfectly.

I appreciate the link to the e-learning. Very helpful, especially since googling for help isn't always fruitful.

Comment: Another great place is the SAS community forums. They've got a pretty active user base there. Good place for targeted programming or procedure-specific tips.